# html form input string as array of characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, input

```
 function reverse(){
    var name_id = document.getElementsByName("name_id");
    var out_id = [];
    for(var i=name_id.length - 1 ; i<name_id.length ; i--) {
        for(var j=0 ; j<name_id.length ; j++) {
            out_id[j] = name_id[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0 ; i<name_id.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("output-3").innerHTML = out_id;
    }
 }
```

Well I'm new to StackExchange.

Btw the javascript code is a function reverse() that reverses the string input in html page. But when I implement it using:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
  <br><br>
  <label class="label label-info" for="Name">Name : </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name_id[]" placeholder="Enter Name">
  <br>
  <label class="label label-success" id="output-3" form="output"></label></div>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="reverse();">Reverse</button>
</form>
```

The page gets stuck and nothing further happens. I want help cuz this is the first time i'm trying to use input data as array and am confused how to do that.
Above code is my effort to understand javascript.
Pls check the code and any modifications or suggestion, pls let me know.

Comment: Ah form submit, doesn't it refresh your page ?

Comment: BTW, are you trying to submit the form ? Or just reverse the string input ?

Comment: I am not getting it? if we use type= "submit" how is it different from type="button"?

Comment: If you use `submit` inside a form, the form will submit the value (to URL specified in `action` attribute) and will refreshes the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop, here:

```
for(var i=name_id.length - 1 ; i<name_id.length ; i--)
```

Your variable `i` gets decremented, so your condition `i < name_id.length` will always be true. You should probably change the condition to `i >= 0`.

Comment: Do I have to put another question for a small doubt in the same code?

Comment: Minipif u are right, i probably missed that infinite loop. #noobme, thanks !

Comment: If it's a small thing related to this question, edit the question and add it at the end.

Comment: Damn, you're quick :D +1

Answer (score 0):

This Demo may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/dh680nkh/1/

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name_id = document.getElementById("name");
    var out_id = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = name_id.value.length; i <= len; i++) {
        out_id.push(name_id.value.charAt(len - i));
    }
    for ( var i = 0; i < out_id.length; i ++ ) {
        document.getElementById("output-3").innerHTML = out_id.join('');
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <br><br>
           <label class="label label-info" for="Name">Name : </label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name_id[]" placeholder="Enter Name">
           <br><label class="label label-success" id="output-3" form="output"></label></div>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" id="submit">Reverse</button></form>
```

Comment: helpful and working! 
I need to get more understanding on choosing methods in javascript , since i m new to this its a good start for me! thank ya.

Comment: what is that e.defaultPrevented for?

Comment: Prevent from the default action of the form, it tells, do not refresh the form. (When you use a link element `a`, and you don't want to execute the link action)

Comment: what is this .value method for ?

Comment: it returns the value that you enter in the `input`

Comment: thnq so much RM ... helped a lot.